# Products in Cart + Abandoned Cart feature - does it affect performance? How can I clear it out?

Tags: cart, performance

So once again I find myself trying to track down "add to cart" performance issues. I was looking at anything related to the cart and noticed that there is a feature in the admin panel `Reports->Products in Cart` that has hundreds of products that were added to the cart and `Reports->Abandoned Carts` that has registered users who have left items in their carts.

My question is, **does this affect performance or are these simply logs?**

Regardless of it it affects performance, how can this be emptied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are simply data which are getting their information from `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_quote_item`.

The log maintenance only removes quotes that have orders (`is_active=0`) which only runs via cron.

There could be a time when you need to delete the orphaned quotes, however you will need to create a custom MySQL query to delete only the ones that have been orphaned for over 60 days or so.